# How do I assoicate two JSON objects together in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

For example 
The app allows a UserAcount to upload an Image, and post it and then other people would be able to comment on it.
I would have two different objects right? One for UserAccount and one for the image that was posted right?
So would it be something like this?

```
{
  “userId”:”1”,
 "userName":"jmcooper",
   "password":"qwer",
   "name":"Jim Cooper",
   "emailAddress":"jim@cooperplanet.com"
} 

{
  “photoId”:”1”,
 "photoName":"something",
   "abstract":"qwe rwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwerwer",
   "uploadedByUserID":"1",
   "comments":"3423423423423"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a reasonable schema for your db. In the script itself I would probably hold a reference to the user instead of the user id in the photo object. Though it really is dependent on what you're going to be doing the most.